# Deploy a sql compact database with installshieldxc xz

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installshield

I have a windows form application that requires users to log in to access the information. I have created a local compact database file for the credentials to be stored. I added the database file to my the folder but when I open my application and try to log in it tells me that it cannot find the database file.

Should the file be stored on a different folder, or should I need to install an instance of sql on the user computer.

This is my first deployment so I am not sure how to go about it. I have done some research on the subject, but it does not seem related to my issue. The help section of Intallshield was not clear either.

I am looking for some resources on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the issue, in order to work all files, including the database files need to be dumped under the userprofile folder.